# Did anybody have problems with migrating Xcode3.2x projects to Xcode4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

At the moment I'm in a production cycle with submitting updates to my App every 2 weeks in average. I'm thinking of migrating to Xcode4 right now. Did anybody have problems with migrating projects or archiving or submitting to store? If so, best practises in solving such issues are very welcome.

Comment: I will start a migration - I decided - and of course report about problems, if ocurr.

Comment: I'll give up. I have JSON and Three20 as dependent projects and I do not get it running under Xcode4. Maybe I'll wait until the Three20 group has a new release. On the other hand, at the moment they have a Bug which lets Three20 crash under iOS3.0. As long as this it not fixed I cannot switch to a new Three20 and thus not to Xcode4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't experienced any problems and the [transition guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/ExistingProject/ExistingProject.html) claims:

> Working on a Project in Xcode 4 Leaves
>   Your Xcode 3 Preferences Untouched

I've also read somewhere else (but can't find it) that Xcode 4 uses the Xcode 3 project format unchanged. So far I can confirm this.

Comment: Sure, but to get some new features working a migration to Xcode4 format might be useful. Thanx for the link to the transition guide.

Comment: There isn't an Xcode 4 format. As the link above notes: "Projects created with Xcode 4 can be opened and built on Xcode 3.2 and later." During the developer preview I switched back and forth between versions without any trouble.

Comment: I encountered crash when I opened a project with xCdoe4, but reopen the same project again, it works well.

Comment: Same here, I also switched back and forth and hadn't any troubles. Neither had my colleagues.

Comment: This may be true, if you do not have other projects your project depends on. If you do, such as I am doing, it can be frustrating to migrate.